# Nodejs amqp library to create connection to HA Rabbitmq Server

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using "amqp" library in my nodejs application to connect to rabbitmq server. Rabbitmq server is configured in Master-Slave mode. The amqp.createConnection(...) , it seems it doesn't allow to configure multiple hosts. Is there a way , where I can specify multiple hosts, such that if one hosts goes down my application should connect to other available node?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node-amqp, the host field of the connection options accepts an array. Unfortunately only host can be an array - not port, authentication etc. (those have to match over all the servers).

Comment: can you provide any example of that?